# What version of Android is on the G1?

Tags: android

I just uploaded my first app to the Android marketplace and one comments says, "It force closes on G1". What version of the Android OS does the G1 use?

Comment: Hi Joseph. Welcome to Stack Overflow :) ... If any of those answers were helpful, you may want to mark one as accepted, by clicking on the green tick next to the answer. Marking answers as accepted will help you receive more answers for any future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Originally the G1 shipped with 1.0, then upgrades were released to update the phone to 1.1, 1.5 (Cupcake) and 1.6 (Donut).

So you would expect most users to be on 1.6.  However, there are a couple of extra things you may want to consider.

Firstly, some users will be running custom firmware.  A quite a few G1 users - me included - run community firmware on their devices, such as [CyanogenMod](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/).  Often these releases are 1.6 releases with 2.x functionality ported from the Android Open Source Project (AOSP) tree, so you could consider them as a hybrid release, putting the phone somewhere between 1.6 and 2.x.  I wouldn't worry about the people running custom firmware since they are so many different firmwares and builds of each firmware, and people who put custom firmware on their phone usually expect to fend for themselves.  I only mention it in case you get some weird bugs you really can't replicate which might be caused by this.

Secondly, I'd recommend looking at [the Android Device Dashboard](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) as this shows what fraction of users of all phones are running each release:

[image: Pie Chart. Mmmm, Pie.]

At the time of writing 31% of users are still on Android 1.5 and I would guess quite a few of these are running G1s.

So my advice would be to test your application on 1.5 and 1.6 if you want to support G1 users.

Answer (score 3):

The latest should have been Android 1.6, but originally it was shipped with Android 1.0 ([Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTC_Dream)).

Answer (score 0):

The latest update they've pushed out to the G1 is Android 1.6.  They're supposed to be working on trimming down 2.0 to make it fit on the G1 but so far it hasn't been available without hacking your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Currently 1.6 (Donut), this is most likely the last OS version that will be on the G1.

Answer (score 0):

Originally it was shipped with Android 1.0. Now it uses Android 1.6